# I am unable to convert make a svg file from PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, svg

I have a psd file, which is has several layers. I took layer which I wanted duplicated to it to a new file( ctrl+n). Then saved the file as .png. Now I opened that png file in adobe, converted it to svg. And I got a svg file, but the issue is some un necessary background. [image: Here is the image, with un necessary background] Now, The svg formed scales accordingly without pixalation. But the background also is scaling. i don't want the background to be scaled. Is that common with svg? or am I doing something wrong. Is there any background layer in the PSD file, that I am taking? [psd file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=86704EA19798B2AA!456&authkey=!ACzdCTKszM0626c&ithint=file%2Cpsd/%22psd%20file%22) Here is the svg [svg](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=86704EA19798B2AA!459&authkey=!ADYBKJURpu6JYuA&ithint=folder%2C)

ps: I'm trying to take arrow from PSD file

Comment: SVG is vector based. PNG is raster based. Why do you want to save a raster image as an SVG?

Comment: Because all I got is a PSD file, from which I have make svg's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert a `.png` (pixel based) image to `.svg` (vector based). The .svg file you supplied merely includes an embedded (pixel) image. This is the cause for the pixelation and the unwanted background.

Your best option is to trace the arrow in Illustrator using the `Pen tool` and save the vector drawing as an svg from there.

Good luck!